# looping string in python

Tags: python, string, loops

I need to do the same analysis on 2000 data files which has a name like abc_0.dat, abc_1.dat .... abc_1999.dat. I wonder is there anyway to make a loop for this kind of problem in python. Here is the script I was working on.

```
from scipy import stats
import numpy as np
import scipy as sp
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import sys
import math

for x in xrange(2000):

gps_time = 932170000 + x*1000
i = str(x)

a_file =$(gps_time).0-$(i).dat

b_file =$(gps_time).0.dat

x = np.loadtxt(a_file, skiprows=1, usecols=[18])
y = np.loadtxt(a_file, skiprows=1, usecols=[17])
z = np.loadtxt(b_file, skiprows=1, usecols=[1])
```

Most of the script are just draft to illustrate the concept of the script

Comment: I don't understand the question. Please clarify...

Comment: Even for illustration, you should use actual Python syntax, which `$(gps_time).0-$(i).dat` isn't.

Comment: Also, you should indent your `for` loop in the above code.

Comment: How did you miss the built-in function [`str()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-str)?

Comment: I am really sorry about that. What I mean is that I want the script to do the same analysis on different data file. But there are 2000 of them and I wonder is there anyway to make a loop for this type of problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the problem with for loop and combining string.

```
for x in xrange (0,2000):
     gps_time = 932170000 + x*1000
     a_file =str(int(gps_time)) + ".0-" + str(x) + ".dat"
     b_file =str(int(gps_time)) + ".0.dat"
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is really badly phrased, but if i get the gist of what you're saying, here's a better way.

(Ensure all the files are in the same directory).

```
import glob
directory = 'path/to/directory' + '*.dat'

files = glob.glob(directory)

for currFile in files:
    function1(currFile)
    function2(currFile)
    # insert whatever else you want to do with currFile here.
```

etc.

Comment: `file` is a bad name for a variable since in Python 2 it masks the alternative name for `open()`.    `fname`?

Comment: It's not meant to be copy pasted as usable code, it was intended as a reference, but i'll update the example. thank you :)